# Python command to distinguish between parquet and delta tables/files

Tags: python, sql, datatables, databricks, parquet

I am working in databricks and want to find out the format of the table.

Something similar to the sql command

```
DESCRIBE DETAIL table_name
```

However, need it to be a python command

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use spark.sql as follows :

```py
describe = spark.sql('DESCRIBE DETAIL database.table_name')
describe.show()

+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|format|                  id|                name|description|            location|           createdAt|       lastModified|  partitionColumns|numFiles| sizeInBytes|properties|minReaderVersion|minWriterVersion|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
| delta|9et752-detae-7932...|database.table_name |       null|dbfs:/mnt/data/t... |2022-02-23 13:07:...|2022-03-22 10:07:16|[year, month, day]|    9431|138273676053|        {}|               1|               2|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

If you just need to retrieve the format, you could do it like this :

```py
format = describe.collect()[0]['format']
format

Out[1]: 'delta'
```

Comment: Thank you that is of great help.

Comment: How could I get    x = database.table_name.  describe = spark.sql('DESCRIBE DETAIL x') to work, thank you

Comment: You could do x=database.table_name and then describe = spark.sql(f'DESCRIBE DETAIL {x}')